# Virus, trojan while Securing .Net assembly with obfuscators

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly, obfuscation, virus

I'm developing vb.net Application, so far so good,

I want to secure my code using an obfuscator 
(tried more then 5 obfuscators),

the problem is that the antivirus signal my application after obfuscation as virus, 
I tried also virustotal.com, and I was surprised by the results.
the problem appears after using the obfuscator. 
any idea how to resolve this problem or how to get more secured application without using obfuscators ?

Comment: Write in C !!!!   Also, list the obfuscators you used,  we assume you paid for them.  If not -- at your own peril.

Comment: don't know how to code in C, I used only trial versions for testing purpose;
I tried enigma protector, themida, confuser, Agiledotnet, skater, babel

Comment: Unfortunately, the very foundation of .NET is open to the world to see your code plain as day.  Obfuscation is the only work-around.  Security through obscurity is no security at all.  So if you write in .NET -- focus more on making a good application, don't embed credentials in source, etc ;  than on 'securing' your product.

Comment: your are right, but there's things that we need to hide like connection string...

Comment: @user2224150 An obfuscator does not really solve this problem. The string is only hidden from plain view, it's still pretty easy to find if you do some basic analysis. Better try to redesign your application such that no secret strings are in it.

Comment: @fuz where or how will I store the secret strings ?

Comment: An obfuscator doesn't "secure" anything at all. Why would a connection string be a secret? Don't hard-code passwords and user names; let Windows do the authentication for you.

Comment: Why you need a secret string in the first place? Asymmetric cryptography doesn't need secret keys. If the application accesses a database, then [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353885/how-to-secure-database-credentials-for-a-client-server-based-java-desktop-applic).

Comment: @user2224150 You need to find a solution that doesn't involve secret strings.

Comment: If the problem is with connectionStrings, Microsoft has a good solution for this: [Secure Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @AxelWass not only connection strings

Comment: @MargaretBloom - a good example of "secret" strings being part of end distribution -- is if the application makes use of an API set which is locked to the app